# How do I format a date to mm/dd/yyyy in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, time

In Perl you can do:

```
my $current_time = DateTime->now();
my $mdy = $current_time->mdy("/");
```

What's the easiest way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you want to do just this in Perl (i.e., you don't want any more from DateTime), I think it's easier to do using the `strftime` function in Perl's POSIX module. See here for more: http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2009-02-26.html.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `strftime` method can be used to format times:

```
Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: +1 However, note that `strftime` is available in Perl as well and http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime has a lot of functionality beyond the simple example here.

Comment: strftime is the name of the underlying C library that implements these format strings. It's the standard name across all languages for this particular date format.

Comment: @mpeters - Just because it's standard doesn't mean it's good. Naming `creat()` without the e at the end was just a terrible design mistake, and naming functions with names like `strftime()` is equally bad. We can see why it was done in the past, but here in the present it's horrible.

Comment: **Note:** This is _mm/dd/yy._ For _mm/dd/yyyy_ use `Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")` (**%Y**).

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use `%D` with **[strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)** method

```
 > Time.now.strftime("%D")
 => "11/24/14"  # mm/dd/yy
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a gem to help with formatting dates, and keeping your views DRY (not having to strftime every time you want to format dates).

Check it out at: http://github.com/platform45/easy_dates

Answer (score -1):

```
my $current_time = DateTime->now();

my_current_time = DateTime.now

my $mdy = $current_time->mdy("/");

my_mdy = my_current_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```