# Ruby - DateTime for Database

Tags: ruby, database, datetime, date

I have a Database column with the syntax "0000-00-00 00:00:00".
In PHP I would do 
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

In Ruby, I do

```
require 'date'
now = DateTime::now()
puts "#{now.year()}-#{now.mon()}-#{now.mday()} #{now.hour()}:#{now.min()}:#{now.sec()}"
```

The result is: 
"2010-1-5 10:16:4"
That's not okay. How could I create a "timestring" with the format "0000-00-00 00:00:00"?

Thanks a lot in advance & Best Regards

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230296/how-do-i-format-a-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-ruby

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can format the dates like in PHP thanks to the built-in `Time` class, see documentation [there](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298).

This would give for your case :

```
t = Time.now
puts t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 3):

A little shorter

```
t = Time.now
puts t.strftime("%F %T")

=> "2015-01-06 14:01:05"
```

Answer (score 3):

iso8601 method can be useful also:

```
>> Time.now.utc.iso8601
=> "2015-05-08T16:45:22Z"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails/ActiveSupport then [to_s(:db)](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/to_s) will be the shortest way:

```
Time.now.to_s(:db)
=> "2017-05-22 11:14:40"
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord tends to store dates / times as UTC, so using `utc` will make your data more consistant

```
t = Time.now.utc
puts t.strftime("%F %T")

=> "2016-05-06 19:05:01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that Rails also stores microsecond precision. That is, microseconds are the 6 digits after the second in the database format:

```
Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N')
=> "2022-10-26 12:30:26.243506"
```

or:

```
Time.now.strftime('%F %T.%6N')
=> "2022-10-26 12:34:37.803091"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Time#to_s(:db)`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/to_s) is being deprecated, use [`Time#to_fs(:db)`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/Time:to_fs) instead.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Time#to_s(:db) is deprecated. Please use Time#to_fs(:db) instead.

**Tip:** it is easier to remember when we know what the short name actually means, and in that case the `f` stands for `formatted`. There's also an alias `to_formatted_s`.